# .show()/.hide() on click

Tags: jquery, html

I have this JQuery function:

```
function JQueryPopup(value) {
    $(value).show();

    $('#JQueryClose').click(function(){
        $(value).hide();
    });

    $( document ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        if ( $( e.target ).closest( elem ).length === 0 ) {
            $(value).hide();
        }
    });

    $( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
        if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { // ESC
            $(value).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

when i call the function it shows a div (value)

How can i use the button/link that was used to open it close it too?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function for show/hide purpose.

But you're binding the event handlers inside a function… note that whenever the function `JQueryPopup` is called (*unless it's binded to `ready` event and only called once*), it'll add a new handler, your code probably won't work as expected afterwards since more than one handlers fire upon the event.

Change your code as follows (*Assuming you want bind the events upon page load*):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#JQueryClose').click(function(){
    $(value).hide();
 });

 $( document ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
    if ( $( e.target ).closest( elem ).length === 0 ) {
        $(value).hide();
    }
 });

 $( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { // ESC
        $(value).hide();
    }
 });
})

function JQueryPopup(value) {
 $(value).toggle(); 
}
```

*side note: you seems to be using different methods for the same purpose such as `click`, `on('click',function(){...})` etc, it's a good practice to be consistant and stick to a particular method*